# Windows store app C# Catch Error

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, try-catch, windows-store

I am developing a Windows store app, however I used this method to generate an `user id` when the app open by first time

```
private string host = "http://etc.com";

public async void RegisterUsuario() {
    string displayName = await UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();
    string url = host + "/json/Register.php?code=" + displayName;
     try
     {
         var http = new HttpClient();
         var jsonText = await http.GetStringAsync(url);
         var jsonValues = JsonArray.Parse(jsonText)[0];
         var status = jsonValues.GetObject().GetNamedString("status");

         if (status == "error")
         {
             var dialog = new MessageDialog("No se pudo registrar tu usuario", "¡Oops!");
             await dialog.ShowAsync();

         }

         else
         {
             ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =          ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
             localSettings.Values["usuario"] = jsonValues.GetObject().GetNamedNumber("id");

         }
     }
     catch {

         alertCatch("No se pudo registrar tu usuario");
     }       
}
```

THE JSON RESPONSE:

> [{"status":"success","id":32}]

The problem:

In my pc always works fine, but when I submit the app to the windows store I always get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FkVN.jpg

the same error that will show the app in the CATCH.

Can you help me, maybe something in the appxmanifest?

In capabilities I selected private and public networks

Comment: Your first step in killing this bug is giving yourself an error you can actually sink your teeth into catch (Exception ex) { alertCatch(ex.message);}  find out what is actually happening and post the error message back to us